# Replacement for UAPush method appReceivedRemoteNotification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

In attempting to upgrade to [Urban Airship 8.0.1](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/releases/tag/8.0.1), the method `appReceivedRemoteNotification` is no longer available.

```
MyClass.swift:55:23: Value of type 'UAPush' has no member 'appReceivedRemoteNotification'
```

[UrbanAirship Library 7.3.0 to 8.0.0](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/ios-migration.html) docs do not mention the method.

Neither is mentioned in the [iOS Changelog](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/ios_changelog.txt).

What is the replacement to `appReceivedRemoteNotification` such that a migration to 8.0.1 can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mentioned in our [migration guide](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/ios-migration.html) and you always check the [appledocs](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Protocols/UAPushNotificationDelegate.html).

We now have 2 methods for when a notification is received:

- receivedForegroundNotification:completionHandler:
- receivedBackgroundNotification:completionHandler:

And 1 method when a notificaiton is opened or notification action button is tapped:

- receivedNotificationResponse:completionHandler:

Comment: the method is mentioned in the migration guide but only in that it is added in 5.0.0. The appledocs link provided gives a 404 unfortunately.

That is useful regarding the replacement methods though. Thanks.

Part of the issue is that we are upgrading from such an old version. Nobody's fault but our own.

Btw any chance you could advise me on the replacement for UATagType?

Comment: Fixed the appledoc link. I accidentally added a period. Let me get back to you about the UATagType.

Comment: UATagType was removed because those tags are now autogenerated for all devices with http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/device-property-tags.html.

If you are not ready to move on from UATagType, you could restore the utils class - https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library-dev/blob/6.4.0/Airship/Common/UATagUtils.m by making a copy of it in your application.

Comment: awesome thanks! Sorry I should probably have raised another question for that.

Comment: sorry am getting into this a bit more. It seems that the method appReceivedRemoteNotification is invoked to "record push conversions, parse the notification and call the appropriate methods on your delegate." Is it still necessary to "record push conversions" or is that handled automatically?

Comment: We do support auto integration so you can most likely remove any app delegate methods. If it causes problems (uses the swizzle) you can do manual integration. http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#automatic-integration